# How to run a file_get_content in a loop?

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to loop it. But when executing this script:

```
    for ( $page_number = 1; $page_number <= $pages_count ; $page_number++ )
    {
        $url = $this->makeURL( $limit, $category->getSources()[0]->getSourceId(), $subCat->getSources()[0]->getSourceId() );
        echo $url."</br>"; // Returns the correct URL
        $json = json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ) );

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r( $json ); //Only return the proper date the first time. Then its always the same whatever the url
        echo "</pre>";

        //$this->insert( $json, $subCat );
        $limit = $limit + 10;
    }
```

The reponse I get in the `file_get_contents()` doesn't match the url called (the parameters changes during the loop of course, its like a pagination, but I always get the first page for no reason.). Even if the URL is ok, it doesn't seem to call this page and always returns the same results. But when I copy and paste the URL from the what I get in the echo to my browser search/url bar, I get the right results.

I have the feeling I'm missing something with `file_get_contents()` maybe to clear the previous call or something.

**EDIT:** This is the makeURL()

```
public function makeURL( $limit, $mainCat, $subCat )
{
    $pagi_start = $limit;
    $url = "http://some.api/V3/event_api/getEvents.php?"
            . "&cityId="    . "39"
            . "&subcat="    . $subCat
            . "&cat="       . $mainCat
            . "&link="      . "enable"
            . "&tags="      . "enable"
            . "&strip_html=". "name,description"
            . "&moreInfo="  . "popularity,fallbackimage,artistdesc"
            . "&tz="        . "America/Los_ Angeles"
            . "&limit="     . $pagi_start.",10";

    return $url;
}
```

Comment: how did you fetched $this->makeURL ..??

Comment: its a method of my class, it returns the correct url (built on different parameters. The Url is correct since, when I echo it, I can copy and paste it and get the correct results. 
But when I see my results in the print_r, its not good

Comment: can you provide the full code please ..

Answer (score 1):

Without providing fuller code, hard to know exactly what is happening. But I have two ideas based on past experience.

First, perhaps the server is simply unable to handle too many requests at once. So I would suggest adding a [`sleep()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) setting in your script to pause between request to give the server a chance to catch up.

```
for ( $page_number = 1; $page_number <= $pages_count ; $page_number++ )
{
    $url = $this->makeURL( $limit, $category->getSources()[0]->getSourceId(), $subCat->getSources()[0]->getSourceId() );
    echo $url."</br>";
    $json = json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ) );

    // Adding a 'sleep()' command with a 10 second pause.
    sleep(10);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $json );
    echo "</pre>";

    //$this->insert( $json, $subCat );
    $limit = $limit + 10;
}
```

The other idea is perhaps the server you are trying to connect to is blocking curl requests?  What happens if you go to the command line and type the following"

```
curl "http://some.api/V3/event_api/getEvents.php?[all parameters here]"
```

Or even check the headers with the `curl -I` option like this:

```
curl -I "http://some.api/V3/event_api/getEvents.php?[all parameters here]"
```

**EDIT:** Looking at your `makeURL()` function shows me another glaring issue.  Pretty sure  you should be using [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/urlencode) on the values.

This is how I would recode your function:

```
public function makeURL( $limit, $mainCat, $subCat )
{
    $pagi_start = $limit;

    // Set the param values.
    $param_array = array();
    $param_array['cityId'] = 39;
    $param_array['subcat'] = $subCat;
    $param_array['cat'] = $mainCat;
    $param_array['link'] = "enable";
    $param_array['tags'] = "enable";
    $param_array['strip_html'] = "name,description";
    $param_array['moreInfo'] = "popularity,fallbackimage,artistdesc";
    $param_array['tz'] = "America/Los_ Angeles";
    $param_array['limit'] = $pagi_start . ",10";

    // Now roll through the param values urlencode them.
    $param_array_urlencoded = array();
    foreach($param_array as $param_key => $param_value) {
      $param_array_urlencoded[$param_key] = urlencode($param_value);
    }

    // Create the final param array.
    $param_array_final = array();
    foreach($param_array_urlencoded as $final_param_key => $final_param_value) {
      $param_array_final[] = $final_param_key . "=" . $final_param_value;
    }

    // Create the final URL with the imploded `$param_array_final`.
    $url = "http://some.api/V3/event_api/getEvents.php?" . implode("&", $param_array_final) ;

    return $url;
}
```

Comment: i'll try the sleep method. Concerning the second point, why is it returning the correct results the first time then ?

Comment: sleep not working :/ Im going to try urlencode and paste the full code

Comment: the urlencode makes things worst as my url is encoded. You don't need it to be encoded. I really have nothing to add to the code, this is a simple as this.